# Meaning of Political Space

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "political space" mean in this context?

> Of course we are mindful that there is no guarantee that our current diplomatic efforts will succeed where others failed, but with the president’s direction and strong support we are committed to try through diplomacy to do more, not less. Over the past year we have been able to sustain **political space** and momentum at home with bipartisan agreement that diplomacy remains the best course. 
>   [Remarks on DPRK at Michigan University](https://www.ncnk.org/node/1854)

I found the following definition but am not sure if it works above.

> Political space is
>   an arena in which input from citizens is continually being received
>   and taken into account by the governing authorities.[Wikija](https://itlaw.wikia.org/wiki/Political_space#cite_note-0)

Comment: In your exact context, "political space" doesn't refer to the metaphorical "political arena" itself. It's effectively referring to the DPRK having "space" (a position they can occupy) ***within*** that arena. But how come you're asking about this ***second*** instance of the word "space"? What did you think it meant a couple of paragraphs earlier, where the writer said *Through direct engagement we [North Korea] must create **space and momentum** for diplomacy*?

Comment: We means the U.S. here since the speaker is the US special representative to the DPRK, Stephen Biegun. I thought in “create space and momentum for diplomacy”, space just meant room or empty area. Then in the sentence I asked, does space mean the Republican’s political strength/position in the U.S.? And are both “space” mean the position of the Republican?

Comment: Well, I only glanced at the original. But it makes no difference whether the writer here is on the US or DPRK side of the diplomatic process. Both of them need metaphorical political "space" and "momentum" to work within. Have you never heard of metaphorical "room to manoeuvre" in the context of negotiations?

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, not really. I’ll google. Thank you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Okay, I just finished googling. Then does space here mean the room to maneuver? Or just the strength/position of the Republican? I’m now confused again.

Comment: ...specifically, diplomats might say they need ["wiggle room to negotiate"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wiggle+room+to+negotiate%22). As is often pointed out, ***All language is metaphor***. Also note how often people in negotiations talk about themselves or the other side ***shifting positions,*** or ***refusing to budge***. You need to think more about how metaphoric language works in English.